# Setting a primary category for content entry

Tags: ee2, categories

At the moment I can add multiple categories to a post which is fantastic. Is there a way to specify which of the selected categories is the primary category for that content?

The reason that I want to select the primary category is to present a clear breadcrumb trail.

For example an article of content could have the following categories:

```
A
   B
      C *
   D *
       E
F *
   G
   H
```

But the bread crumbs should reflect the primary category "C" (for example).

A > B > C > The Content Title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a commercial addon called [Primary Category](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/primary_category/) by Solspace which is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'd continue using the traditional method of defining categories associated with your entry, but, in order to specify the "primary" category, I'd use an add-on like [Lonely Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lonely-cat), which allows you to store a single category in a channel field. Then, I'd use that primary category to feed an add-on like [GWcode Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories), which should be able to generate the categorical portion of your breadcrumb structure.

Comment: Does "Lonely Cat" automatically tick the category for the content as well? (In the case where only one category is specified).

Comment: I don't have any idea; I'd suggest pursuing CreateSean's answer anyways - that looks to be exactly what you need.